# Using module annotations as method attributes

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

So here's an interesting question, what I look at the documentation for module attributes in elixir i.e. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html at the bottom it mentions that they can be used as method annotations as in ExUnit.

Unfortunately there is basically no information on how to achieve this and looking through ExUnit code has just got me lost. It seems like I would need to determine the closest method to the attribute to say that they are associated in some way (could be wrong though).

Any idea where I might look to learn about this?

Comment: Have you seen this page? http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html  More specifically this section of that page seems relevant to your question: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html#module-tags Is there something on this page that is unclear to you?  Your question isn't very clear to me.

Comment: I dont know what your showing, me yes ExUnit has @tags that act as annotations to functions, my question was how they achieved this. I actually solve it messing around with things, and now I have another problem of actually been able to do anything useful with these annotation at compile time. Here my pay around: https://github.com/chrisjowen/annotatable

Comment: Ok, then take my comment as a sign that it's not terribly clear what you want to know.

Comment: Cheers @OnorioCatenacci I don't know how to make this any cleared, the title basically said it all. Feel free to suggest how.

Comment: "Any idea where I might look to learn about this?" _this_ being what exactly?  Associating an annotation with a test in ExUnit or is there some other property of an annotation which is unclear to you?  It seems it cannot be the former because that's spelled out in the documentation you reference--you just put the annotation on the line immediately before your test definition.  So assuming you have some other question, where precisely did you state it that I missed?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think we need to stop this discussion now. It was obvious by the answer that others understood this. The question was not related to ExUnit it was simple an example of a library that had done exactly what I was looking to achieve and I had trouble initially following the code there. The suggested answer help clarify what was going on. If you feel still that this question is unclear then feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this. Look at source code of [ExUnit.Case](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex).

At first, look into `__using__` macro, since it will be invoked first when you use it in a test case. Particularly, note [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L206)

```
    Enum.each [:ex_unit_tests, :tag, :describetag, :moduletag, :ex_unit_registered],
      &Module.register_attribute(__MODULE__, &1, accumulate: true)
```

This registers `@tag` and a bunch of more attributes as accumulated. Read the docs of [Module.register_attribute/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#register_attribute/3), and you will see it means anytime attribute is invoked, the value gets appended to a list of previous attributes.

Then note `test/3` macro, particularly [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L259)

```
quote bind_quoted: [var: var, contents: contents, message: message] do
  name = ExUnit.Case.register_test(__ENV__, :test, message, [])
  def unquote(name)(unquote(var)), do: unquote(contents)
end
```

Note the call to `ExUnit.Case.register_test/4`. Looking at it, specially [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L404)

```
tag = Module.delete_attribute(mod, :tag)
```

It fetches the tags until here, and deletes them. And by having the tags, and the name of test, it invokes ([here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L425))

```
test = %ExUnit.Test{name: name, case: mod, tags: tags}
Module.put_attribute(mod, :ex_unit_tests, test)
```

which saves the test along with tags inside another attributes.

And at last, note here

```
  @doc false
  defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
    quote do
      def __ex_unit__(:case) do
        %ExUnit.TestCase{name: __MODULE__, tests: @ex_unit_tests}
      end
    end
  end
```

The function `__ex_unit__/1` is called in [ExUnit.Runner.run_case/3](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/runner.ex#L120) to get information of tests inside each case.

You see the point? Use an accumulated attribute, inside your macro call a function that always gets current value of the attribute and clears it, then do anything you want with the value, because you know it is always for when the macro is called.

I hope it was clear enough, drop a comment if you need more explanation.

PS. I just read the source code to find this out. It was exciting to know how it works.

Comment: I accept the answer as this is pretty much spot on. I had actually figured this out and knocked up that little library for annotating any method. As you said the important part was accumulate: tag of the register_attribute. Its pretty nice that elixir doesn't really support method annotations but the language is hackable enough to just do it yourself :)

Comment: Oh, one more thing to mention if anyone else was interested in this. ExUnit requires that the test macro is called which in turn retrieves and deletes the attributes defined before it. If we are defining a method then no macro will be called that we can plugin into, but fortunately there is a module lifecycle method we can use @on_defenition (see https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html)